# Saving rendering filter as variable

Tags: c++, image, opengl

I'm writing an image class for a game I'm working on and some images I need rendered with different filters than others, is there a way to save OpenGL filter (GL_LINEAR, GL_NEAREST etc.) in a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well of course it is possible. But you can use any value you like, as long as you use the right token when doing the call to `glTexParameteri` for actually setting the filter before commencing drawing with the texture in question. In later versions of OpenGL you can also use sampler objects to encapsulate a set of filtering settings.